# Design an algorithm that sorts sequences in O(nloglogn)

Tags: algorithm, runtime, analysis

The input is a sequence of n integers with many duplications, such that the number of distinct integers in the sequence is O(log n). Design a sorting algorithm (based on comparisons only) to sort such sequences using at most O(n log log n) comparisons in the worst case.

Can someone explain why I should use a red-black tree instead of merge-sort or some other sorting algo. In addition how can i calculate big o to become n log log n.

Answer (score 2):

since you are using red black tree you have log(n) insertion in this tree you will have distinct elements only and keep count of each element
so you have log(n) elements only and their counts.
to sort you need to insert n elements to the tree which size should be log(n) at maximum so you need nlog(log(n)) for the whole thing and when you have the tree you could simply traverse it in sorted order and repeat each element k times where k is that element count.